# jquery on('click', function()) triggering unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, onclick, modal-dialog

I am having a brain fart today or something, because when i set up an `on('click')` event it is firing like it has been clicked.

```
var myJsFunctions = {
    confirmDelete: function (index) {
        $('#deleteRecipient').modal('show');
        $('#confirmRecipientDeletion').on('click',myJsFunctions.deleteRecipient(index));
    },

    deleteRecipient: function (index) {
        $('#deleteRecipient').modal('hide');
        $('#recipientIsDeleted_' + index).val(true);
        $('#recipient_' + index).hide();
    }
}
```

but when i click the button that fires `confirmDelete`, it runs all the way through the `myJsFunctions.deleteRecipient` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you actually invoking your function and you pass as a handler function execution result from `return` statement.

You should pass function handler instead:

```
$('#confirmRecipientDeletion').on('click', function() {
    myJsFunctions.deleteRecipient(index);
});
```

Comment: sometimes, ugh.  I've been working with too much knockout lately

Answer (score 0):

You have made the mistake in on click jquery syntax.
Change you code like this :

```
var myJsFunctions = {
confirmDelete: function (index) {
    $('#deleteRecipient').modal('show');
    $('#confirmRecipientDeletion').on('click',function(){
       myJsFunctions.deleteRecipient(index);
    });
},

deleteRecipient: function (index) {
    $('#deleteRecipient').modal('hide');
    $('#recipientIsDeleted_' + index).val(true);
    $('#recipient_' + index).hide();
}
```

}